# Abraham’s Childhood

Tags: abraham, genesis-bereishith

Why doesn’t the Torah detail Abraham’s upbringing or just talk more about his childhood and family and how he discovered Hashem? Like by Moshe Rabbeinu, the savior of Israel, his whole life since he was a baby is written in the Pesukim. So I would think that Avraham, the father of our religion, should have his life explained a little more, but rather he Torah instantly starts with him as an adult. Yes, there’s midrashim about destroying his fathers idols since he was a child, or Midrashim about how he used logic to discover Hashem, but why not write stuff like this in the pesukim. I would think how he discovered Hashem is the most important thing, but the Torah merely starts off with “lech lecha.”

Comment: Maharal -- the Jews are chosen because ... God chose us. It's God's business, not ours.

Comment: It’s to bring out the point that it’s greater to do something when your commanded to do it. That’s why it starts his story from lech lecha.